# How to code switch Mobile Data on / off and check current Status on all Android Versions?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I try to find a way to switch Mobile Daten on or off or check the current status on Android.

I search way to to that on all versions of Android (2.3+).

I already found a lot of code to do that. Also on Stack Overflow. But non of that really worked stable. Is there any stable and good coded solution somewhere?

Maybe a special Function/Class to do access that easily?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google took this command away from the developer but it works on older phones.  I think on anything after lolipop you cant do this anymore.